# How do I bind to a property of an object under a collection of collections?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an `ObservableCollection` of a class (TopLevel) that contains a name property and a list of another `ObservableCollection` of class (BottomLevel) that has just a name property. The binding on the highest list works, but when I try to bind to the property on the BottomList I get nothing. What am I missing here?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" DataContext="topList">
    <Border BorderBrush="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="5">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="ic1">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=TopName}"/>
                        <Border BorderBrush="AntiqueWhite" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="5">
                            <Button Content="{Binding Path=BottomList.BottomName}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                
        </ItemsControl>            
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<TopLevel> topList;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        topList = new ObservableCollection<TopLevel>();
        topList.Add(new TopLevel("T" + (1 + topList.Count).ToString()));
        topList[0].AddBottom();
        topList.Add(new TopLevel("T" + (1 + topList.Count).ToString()));
        topList[1].AddBottom();
        ic1.ItemsSource = topList;            
    }
}

public class TopLevel
{
    private ObservableCollection<BottomLevel> bottomList;
    private string topName;

    public void AddBottom()
    {
        bottomList.Add(new BottomLevel("B" + (1 + bottomList.Count).ToString()));
    }

    public TopLevel(string x)
    {
        bottomList = new ObservableCollection<BottomLevel>();
        topName = x;
    }

    public string TopName
    {
        get
        {
            return topName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (topName!=value)
            {
                topName = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<BottomLevel> BottomList
    {
        get
        {
            return bottomList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (bottomList!=value)
            {
                bottomList = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class BottomLevel
{
    private string bottomName;

    public BottomLevel(string x)
    {
        bottomName = x;
    }

    public string BottomName
    {
        get
        {
            return bottomName;
        }
        set
        {
            if (bottomName!=value)
            {
                bottomName = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to bind to the first BottomLevel's BottomName in BottomList? {Binding BottomList/BottomName} may work in that case. http://www.wpftutorial.net/BindingExpressions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one item in BottomList Then you can use the below code for Button

```
 <Button Content="{Binding Path=BottomList[0].BottomName}" Height="50"/>
```

If you want to Bind the BottomList to some List Control you can bind to the DataGrid then you can use the below code.

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid" DataContext="topList">
    <Border BorderBrush="AliceBlue" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="5">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="ic1">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=TopName}"/>
                        <Border BorderBrush="AntiqueWhite" Grid.Column="1"    BorderThickness="5">
                            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BottomList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <Button Content="{Binding Path=BottomName}" Height="50"/>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                          </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

---

Please let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 3):

Your path for the button is incorrect. BottomList does not have a "Name" property, so you can't bind to it. Instead, just use `BottomName` as your path.

Since your `topList` has a collection of "BottomLevel" you'll need some sort of nested items control to iterate over the "bottomList" collection (then use "BottomName" for your path as above).

As it stands, you basically have:

```
<ItemsControl //List of TopLevel>
//Your data context is now the TopLevel item itself
<Button Path=/> //What goes here? you have a whole collection of BottomLevel items to choose from!
</ItemsControl>
```